# GitLab runner submodule update init problem

Tags: git-submodules, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using `GitLab Community Edition 15.8.0`. I have two private repo which are `module1` and `mkdocstest`. I am using GitLab-runner to make the ci/cd process. `mkdocstest` include the `module1` repo as a submodule. I am using the part below in the `yml` file.

```
before_script:
  - export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1
  - git submodule update --init
```

I am getting an error while `submodule update init process`. Since I tried a lot of ways by reading the relevant issues, there are many different error messages. That is why I didn't paste the error message directly. There are many solution suggestions that are below:

1. Use an ssh address for the submodule instead of HTTPS.
2. Activate runner for submodule too.
3. Enter the path of the main repo to the access-token region of subrepo.
4. Add `ssh://` to the `.gitmodules` file at the URL part.

As I saw from the other posts, this problem caused a lot of reasons because many people said it is solved by this but not that, as different from each other.

I wanted to learn what is the correct way of doing such a process. For example, a runner can access the main repo which is private but cannot access a private submodule. Is this a fact? if it is why it is so while both are private?

It looks like different questions but both serve the same issue in this post I think.

Note: (I don't know if it helps but when I make a submodule public, the error maintains. However, it is solved when I change the directory of the submodule after made public. the same behaviour is shown in reverse. When it started to clone a public submodule, it continue to clone when I make it private. However, if I change the submodule directory, it again gives an error while cloning the submodule.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check first if those error messages are centered around an authentication issue.

For instance, "[Private Repo Submodule Setting for GitLab CI](https://medium.com/@sky.tienyu/private-repo-submodule-setting-for-gitlab-ci-47979ab28b9)" ([from Tien](https://medium.com/@sky.tienyu)) suggests to register a deploy token able to access through HTTPS to the submodule declared URLS.

```yaml
# gitlab-ci.yml...## only for https ##before_script:
  - apk add --no-cache git
  - git config --global url."@gitlab.com/">https://${CI_ACCESS_USERNAME}:${CI_ACCESS_TOKEN}@gitlab.com/".insteadOf "https://gitlab.com/"
  - git submodule sync --recursive
  - git submodule update --init --recursive## for ssh & https ##before_script:
 - |
    git config --file .gitmodules --get-regexp url | while read url; do
    git config --file=.gitmodules $(echo "$url" | sed -E "s/git@gitlab.com:|https:\/\/gitlab.com\//https:\/\/${CI_ACCESS_USERNAME}:${@gitlab.com">CI_ACCESS_TOKEN}@gitlab.com\//")
  done
  git submodule sync
  git submodule update --init --recursive
```